# Dell OMSA Remote Enablement? What is it for?

Tags: monitoring, remote, dell-openmanage

I'm managing a group of Dell and HP servers the were put in service before I came into this group. My prior experience is with HP DL3x0 servers. There wasn't any remote management before I joined the group, but I've set up both HP SIM and Dell IT Assistant to email me with issues.

When updating the OMSA software on the Dell servers sometimes the install reports that "Remote Enablement" isn't configured, since it isn't critical I can install/update OMSA anyway,but I'd like to know what functionality this would add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows you to use a different machine to run OMSA's web interface. There, before login, you could click on 'Manage Remote Node', and input the address and credentials of the dell server.

It's mainly useful for situations where OMSA's web interface is not available on the machine, but the rest of OMSA's agents are, eg, VMWare ESXi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

Seemed like a lot of hoops to jump though to get it turned on, so would it be safe to say in a vanilla Windows Server install on a physical server there isn't much reason to enable it?

Comment: If you're only managing the machine locally (though the Server Administrator), you don't need it.